# How to create view that pulls data from different table each month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have new table each month that is basically the same only it contains data for that month. For example

```
Table_201510 -- for October
Table_201511 -- for November and so on...
```

I want to create a view that will give me the possibility to get data for current month in uniform way. For example:

```
select * from vwTable_CurrentMonth
```

Is there a way of doing this without `sp_executesql` , like maybe creating an alias or something?

Comment: Afaik, you cannot create a view that queries a dynamic table, no. Well, unless you query directly from the Master tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a view vwTable_CurrentMonth that you modify each time you create a new table to select from that new table.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I used. I thought there is something like alias or something that would allow me to do this in another way